# What Horde race is better for a priest?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I want to make a priest for healing. In PvP and PvE, which Horde race is better?

Comment: You still have to start leveling it? Take a Goblin, only because you'll have a fun starting zone. Other than that, this isn't really a question

Comment: @Ivo - it's a perfectly fine question and one that more players should consider, rather than just rolling a BE because it's the only "normal" looking Horde race.

Comment: There are so many things to consider when picking a race, that letting it depend on your class is an ignorant one. This question lacks any context to base a judgement on. Thankfully, @Shaun gives an excellent breakdown!

Comment: Is there any other information you require of an acceptable answer to this question?

Answer (score 15):

**Short answer**

It depends. Here's a quick sheet based on my experience if you'd rather not think too much about the options:

- If your goal is to PvP, it's pretty even between Goblin, Tauren, or Undead. Personally, I'd probably go Goblin.
- If you want to be an enchanter, roll a Blood Elf.
- If you want to be an alchemist, roll a Goblin.
- If you want to be an herbalist, roll a Tauren.
- If you don't want to be any of these professions, roll a Goblin.

**Long Answer**

Race differences are pretty negligible. Any race can be an effective priest. What it usually comes down to are the professions you want to roll and whether you are going to be a raider or a PvP player and how much fun you'll have playing the starting area or simply walking around looking like a member of that race.

That being said, you have 5 options as Horde. Here are their noteworthy abilities. I don't bother mentioning things like resistances or extra time underwater as they really aren't all that helpful overall. I already indicated my opinion above, but depending on your personal preference (maybe you really hate being feared and favor an Undead for their ability to break fear effects overall), the lists below may guide you in another direction.

**[Blood Elf](http://www.wowhead.com/race=10#racial-traits)**

- Bonus to enchanting. Since tailoring/enchanting is a good profession combo for a priest, the bonus will help slightly in leveling your skill.
- Free silence/PvE Interrupt/mana restore.

**[Goblin](http://www.wowhead.com/race=9#racial-traits)**

- Bonus to alchemy. Herbalism/alchemy is another good profession combo for a priest.
- Free "disengage" (blast away from enemies).
- The rest of their racials are worth mentioning when combined: cheaper vendor items, access to your bank from anywhere, and faster cast times.

**[Tauren](http://www.wowhead.com/race=6#racial-traits)**

- Bonus to herbalism. Herbalism/alchemy is another good profession combo for a priest.
- Additional health.
- Free AoE stun.

**[Troll](http://www.wowhead.com/race=8#racial-traits)**

- Temporary casting speed increase.
- Shorter snare effects.
- Slight health regeneration.

**[Undead](http://www.wowhead.com/race=5#racial-traits)**

- Free quick heal after combat.
- Free "Charm/Fear/Sleep" effect interrupt.

Comment: This is a really good list, but you *severely* underestimate the value of 'faster cast times' that Goblins have. At the endgame, 1% Haste is basically like having an entire piece of gear as a leg up on others.

Comment: Oh, and the Blood Elf racial, Arcane Torrent, also restores mana, which makes them a fairly strong option for healers specifically, in both PvE and PvP.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, added the bit about mana restore on Arcane Torrent. As for the haste bonus, I agree that it's a pretty significant bonus, but I also think that it's not a make-or-break talent. You can top the DPS/heal meters without it, but it certainly doesn't hurt. Usually, my decision tree for rolling a character post-Cataclysm involves trying to find a reason NOT to roll a Goblin. :)

Comment: "Temporary casting time increase" is confusing, it sounds opposite to the way beserking works. It should be "Temporary casting *speed* increase"

Comment: @ghoppe: Good call. Edited.

Comment: @Delameko: totally wrong. This bonus also increases by 10 the crafts you can make, actually allowing you to level up the profession using cheaper enchants for more levels. For example you can get 15 points using Abyss Shatter instead of just 5 points. You save A WHOLE LOT of any-level materials due to that!

Comment: @Shaun: it's important to notice that the BE and the Tauren AOEs matter only in PvP, since in PvE you'll almost always be too far for that.

Comment: @Delameko: no, profession bonus racials work as follows: "difficulty" and chance of skill point increase is based on your unmodified score, but "available recipes" is based on your modified score. So having a racial bonus is actually a huge advantage leveling, because you get access to all recipes 10 or 15 points earlier than you should, and they last 10 points longer. In your example, you should be cutting diamonds; for a Draenei they all stay orange until 525 (modified skill) instead of turning yellow at 515.

Comment: I don't remember now, it was a long time ago.  It just seemed like my jewelcrafter took longer in the last 10 levels than all my other professions (I have all maxed).  I only had one recipe that was not grey, but maybe I forgot to buy some recipes or something.  I'll delete my original comment to avoid misinformation, as I can't really be bothered to look into it at this point.

Answer (score 2):

**PVE**

- Trolls and Goblins make the best PVE Priests.
- Trolls have Berserking which increases attack speed and more importantly casting speed by 20% (as of 4.2) for 10 seconds making Trolls better at healing and attacking (especially useful in raids and dungeons) than Goblins and critical moments i.e. boss goes into rage.
- Goblins have a passive ability (Time is money) that increases casting speed by 1% constantly making them better over an entire dungeon/raid or when questing in a group.

**PVP**

- Taurens make the best PVP priests.
- Taurens have War stomp which stuns enemies in a radius of 8 yards for 2 seconds which can be a life saver in battlegrounds, They also have Endurance which increases their base health by 5% which (coupled with a priests superior healing) makes Tauren priests the hardest priest to kill and as an added bonus Nature spells are less likely to hit Tauren because of their resistance which is useful as a defence against Druids and Shamans.
- Undead priests are somewhat useful as they cannot be Charmed, Feared or put to Sleep however PVP trinkets can neutralise these effects anyway, however they do have a shadow resistance which is useful against pesky warlocks.

**Overall**

- Overall for both PVE and PVP I'd say a Troll would make the best priest regardless of spec because their Berserking helps deal intense healing and damage, Voodoo shuffle reduces movement impairing effects by 15% which is great for PVP and Regeneration regenerates a Troll's health by 10% of the normal rate in **combat!** as well as increasing the base rate by 10% when not in combat.

Answer (score 1):

At one time, early on in the game the priests did have racial spells.  For instance, only Dwarfs had fear ward, only Forsaken had Devouring Plague.  When these spells were removed (I believe around 3.0) or given to priests of all races, only the basic racial skills came into focus.

In summary:
PVP:
Goblins for Rocket Jump, Undead for WotF

PVE:
Goblins for haste, Trolls for Berserking

But I feel that only high level PvP will bring the racial differences into any sort of significant primacy.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain this assertion is true. While I don't claim to know the exact differences and long-term implications, this site (http://www.wowpedia.org/Races) seems to indicate the races have very subtle differences and still have racial abilities. Not that I really think those are *important*, but still they don't seem to be exactly equal.

Comment: Yes, Races do have minor differences, but when the gear dropping in cata has bonuses to attributes in the +200s I don't think the odd 1 or 2 here or there will make a noticeable difference.

Comment: Mag is right - the racials are still there and they are still considered an important part of the gameplay. But by no means should they be ignored when creating a character.

Comment: Unless you're incredibly concerned about min/maxing your character, the decision really just comes down to "What racials seem cool to me?"

Comment: It's WoW, it's not a role playing game. Minmaxing is all we have!

Answer (score 0):

Trolls are great because of the Berserking ability, but Blood Elf is the best race really because of Arcane Torrent which is a silence and mana restore. Good Luck