# What is a good PvP Horde race for Warlocks in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I would like to know the benefits each race would have to my warlock. I plan on doing a lot of pvp, so that's my first priority.

I don't yet own the full game, so I can only get to lvl 20 (if that matters).
Thanks for any help!

Comment: I have made an attempt to clean up the question to be more answerable. I suggest that this question be reopened.

Comment: In the meantime, see the answer to this question as well: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15202/what-horde-race-is-better-for-a-priest/15218#15218

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's start by summarizing what each race will bring to the table, leaving out the racials that are irrelevant or largely useless to a PvP warlock:

- Orc: A [minor spell power boost](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=33702) every 2 minutes, a [5% pet damage boost](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=54562), and a [15% stun duration reduction](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=20573).
- Troll: [15% snare duration reduction](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=58943) and a [20% haste boost every 3 minutes](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=26297).
- Undead: [Dispel charm/fear/sleep](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=7744) every 2 minutes.
- Blood Elf: [Instant AoE silence and minor mana restore](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=28730) every 3 minutes. (Note: Only has an 8 yard range, so you probably won't be using it against enemy spellcasters.)
- Goblin (available if you buy the Cataclysm expansion): A [rocket jump](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=69070).

In PvP burst damage is king, so the standout abilities (on paper) are the Orc's spell power or the Troll's haste abilities. The Undead's ability to remove charm/fear/sleep is also very useful, but there are items you can easily obtain which can do the same thing.

I'd be less inclined to choose Blood Elf or Goblin because I don't really view their racials as useful in PvP (again, as a Warlock), but honestly, you can excel at PvP with any race. It largely comes down to flavor and personal choice.

Comment: I realize that Warlocks can't be Tauren, but it seems a shame to not mention them along with every other horde race.

Comment: I forgot, does WotF share a CD with trinket or is that just the Human ability?

Comment: Thanks i chose undead cause every time i do warsong i get locked down and their racial ability helps me get out

Comment: @Nick T: Yes, using WotF puts a 30-second cooldown on your PvP trinket.

Comment: @Brant: Don't dismiss the Blood Elf Racial as useless. It's one of the strongest for PvP on the horde. The range is short, but there are usually a lot of good reasons to stay in close range to your enemy since you usually will want to hit a Howl of Terror anyway.

Comment: @Tigraine: Good point, I didn't think of that.

Comment: You forgot the extra haste on goblins.